# judgment of currency for In-app-billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, currency, in-app-billing

I am in the process of creating an in-app-billing service. I want to set prices differently for different countries.

When the purchase page is displayed, how can I decide which currency i should use for an In-app-billing item? Do I use the local currency? Or the Android Market Account currency? I could not find any documentation about this. I want to know the rule of judgment to display the correct currency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402172/android-market-in-app-purchase-how-to-get-the-currency-a-user-will-pay-in), which is already solved

Answer (score 0):

See this question and the corresponding answers:

[Android Market In-App-Purchase: How to get the currency a user will pay in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402172)

In summary, it's not possible (at the time of my writing this!) to talk to Android Market and get the currency of the user's Android Market account.

Maybe an idea to have a Spinner in your shop screen which allows the user to select the currency to display prices in. Bit of a hack but best alternative I could come up with.