# android inapp purchase product price in local currency

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

Is it possible to get product price in local currency from the app itself. For example if I am selling Product1 with price of 1$ through Google Play In App billing. A customer from UK clicks on a button to purchase the product and the price at Google Play is shown in GBP. Can I get localized price in the app from Google Play so I can display it to the customer in its own currency?

Comment: did you check whether in app billing is supported in your country??

Comment: I don't see how this matters. I am developing an app for the client whose country supports in app billing. I just want to show the customers who are buying items from the app, the price of the product in their currency (which they will see in any case after they press the buy button and go to Google Play product site)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are asking this i suggest to just leave as it is.

This is more about economy rather than programming, and the problem is that the ratio between 2 currencies keeps changing every time and there is no way to calculate this because of the market and the actual evaluation is only given by the stock markets for a particular point in time.

There are 2 ways of thinking about this:

- The merchant makes an evaluation about what is the average ratio between 2 currencies, he quantifies this value in real money and adds it to the final price, so he can avoid money loss or at least a good part of it
- The merchant puts in place a mechanism for prices that, given real-time infos from the stock markets ( probably you have to pay for this ), calculates prices of real goods in real time or every time that the user wants to checkout his order.

If this is new to you don't say nothing about this, there are a lots of money that are burning and magically appearing every day in every stock exchange market, if you give a bad advice to your client he can be really disappointed and lose a lot of money.

Also different currencies are usually handled directly by credit card services, there is no reason to handle this by yourself, you can only risk more than it's worth doing it.

If your users wants to know the price in their currency teach them to use Google or some reliable online currency converter.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, or I've stated my question in wrong context. When you define the price of the product in Google Play it automatically calculates the price for different currencies (based on your input). I would like to get the values in different currencies from the Google Play itself and reference to it from my android app. This would be the same price that Google Play would state during checkout in the currency which is presented to the customer.

Comment: @kjurkovic this are universal economic rules: there is no way of doing what are you asking, probably Google Play accepts to lose money by doing this. there are contacts at the end of this page, but i really think that Google Play will handle this http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html

Comment: IAB Version 3 has this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402172/android-market-in-app-purchase-how-to-get-the-currency-a-user-will-pay-in

Answer (score 7):

The in-app billing v3 claims to be able to accomplish this:

> The API also introduces a long-anticipated feature: the ability to query in-app product information directly from Google Play. Developers can now programmatically obtain an item's title, description and price. No currency conversion or formatting is necessary: prices are reported in the user's currency and formatted according to their locale

Source: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/12/in-app-billing-version-3.html