# Test in App Billing in other countries

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing

I've developed a app and some logs are reporting errors when a brasilian user tries purchase an item.

I'm not brasilian and I want to test my app in that country. Is it even possible? My app is european so I tried with USA: I tried with a north american google account, I've changed the store with "Market enabler" to USA with no success. Google Play gives me back the prizes en euros, I'm not connecting as a northamerican but european.

thanks!

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402172/android-market-in-app-purchase-how-to-get-the-currency-a-user-will-pay-in